# Collapsing Survey Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset that looks like this:

| Criteria | Answer | frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Criteria 1 | Answer A | arbitrary integer |
| Criteria 2 | Answer B | arbitrary integer |

For each criterion, there is a range of answer options in the survey ranging from A to E, and there are 4 criteria. However, there are multiple instances of the criteria in the table.

I am trying to find out how I can collapse the information by criteria i.e. for each criteria, what is the spread of answers given by the respondents, in percentage form?

I have tried using groupby but to no avail.

Comment: Please provide a wider data sample containing different criteria and different answers. In addition, please add a code snippet to show what you have done so far and where you are stuck exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PLEASE NOTE I HAVE USED BY MISTAKE frequency float values and NOT integers.

sample data:

```
      Criteria    Answer  frequency
0   Criteria 1  Answer A        0.1
1   Criteria 1  Answer A        0.2
2   Criteria 1  Answer A        0.6
3   Criteria 1  Answer A        0.3
4   Criteria 1  Answer B        0.7
5   Criteria 1  Answer B        0.4
6   Criteria 1  Answer B        0.9
7   Criteria 2  Answer A        0.1
8   Criteria 2  Answer A        0.1
9   Criteria 2  Answer A        0.1
10  Criteria 2  Answer C        0.1
11  Criteria 2  Answer C        0.4
12  Criteria 2  Answer C        0.7

df.groupby(["Criteria", "Answer"]).apply(lambda x: x.min())
```

Output:

```
                     frequency
Criteria   Answer
Criteria 1 Answer A        0.5
           Answer B        0.5
Criteria 2 Answer A        0.0
           Answer C        0.6


df.groupby(["Criteria", "Answer"]).apply(lambda x: x.median())
```

Output

```
                     frequency
Criteria   Answer
Criteria 1 Answer A       0.25
           Answer B       0.70
Criteria 2 Answer A       0.10
           Answer C       0.40


df.groupby(["Criteria", "Answer"]).apply(lambda x: x.std())
```

Output

```
                        frequency
Criteria   Answer
Criteria 1 Answer A  2.160247e-01
           Answer B  2.516611e-01
Criteria 2 Answer A  1.699675e-17
           Answer C  3.000000e-01
```

if you do .reset_index():

```
df.groupby(["Criteria", "Answer"]).apply(lambda x: x.std()).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
     Criteria    Answer     frequency
0  Criteria 1  Answer A  2.160247e-01
1  Criteria 1  Answer B  2.516611e-01
2  Criteria 2  Answer A  1.699675e-17
3  Criteria 2  Answer C  3.000000e-0
```